# Javascript Bug/Glitch?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have this modified Matrix Javascript Code and I want to get rid of the first run of all the strings which overlap themselves. Does anybody have an idea how I can manage that ? Also I want to use this code multiple times on my webpage I need to declare new variables dont it? But when I use it on different pages I dont have to do that, right ? However, I tried both and it didnt work... I would appreciate any help. Thanks 
You can see the full code here: 
https://codepen.io/eriik-re/pen/EXYOXm

This is my js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

document.getElementById("c").style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255)';

c.height = 450;
c.width = window.innerWidth;

//chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
var chinese = ["paylessshoes.com.au" , 
"ralphlaurenoutlet.com.au","uloadit.com.au" ,"forsterbus.com.au", 
"deanwoods.com.au" , "deanwoods.com.au" , "agelessinstantly.com.au", 
"stayhuman.com.au" , "lyndhursthotel.com.au" , "gothicweddings.com.au" , 
"growing-home.com.au" , "veglife.com.au" , 
"anagomes.com.au","soulcentralsydney.com.au" , 
 "manninghammedicalcentre.com.au" ];


var font_size = 15;
var columns = c.width/font_size; //number of columns for the rain
//an array of drops - one per column
var drops = [];
//x below is the x coordinate
//1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
for(var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
drops[x] = 1; 

//drawing the characters
function draw()
{
//White BG for the canvas
//translucent BG to show trail
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

ctx.fillStyle = "#243c84"; //blue text
ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
//looping over drops
for(var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++)
{
    //a random chinese character to print
    var text = chinese[Math.floor(Math.random()*chinese.length)];
    //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
    ctx.fillText(text, i*font_size, drops[i]*font_size);


//sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
    //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
    if(drops[i]*font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.980)
        drops[i] = 0;

    //incrementing Y coordinate
    drops[i]++;
 }
}

setInterval(draw, 150); </script>
```

And HTML:
 `<canvas id="c"></canvas>`

Comment: What's the bug?

Comment: Well, If you look at the pen, during the initialization and the first drop, every 'name' overlaps and it doesnt look good as you cant read anything . I mean the first block of line which drops. I'm assuming it is all the strings I've put in together. After that everything is fine. even it doesnt have to be a bug but I would like to have that removed if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove descent of the overlapping first line, you can initialize the drop y offset to the row below the bottom of the canvas, instead of to the top row:

```
var rowOffCanvas = Math.ceil( c.height/font_size) + 1;
for(var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
    drops[x] = rowOffCanvas;  // instead of 1
}
```

In consequence the drawing function can easily be optimized so as to not draw off canvas:

```
if( drops[i] < rowOffCanvas) {
    ctx.fillText(text, i*font_size, drops[i]*font_size);
}
```

If you have multiple, different, drop effects on the same page, they will need separate storage of their data values (obviously and as you assume). Commonly this would be achieved by storing all data for a single drop effect (including canvas context) in an object unique to each effect. Choosing to do this using object literals, constructor functions or class declarations is up to you, bearing in mind that class declaration are part of ES6 and not supported by IE.